# Dynamic View creation performance issue

Tags: android, json, templates, listview, dynamic

I need to create dynamic layout (i.e. without using xml at all ). On the mobile device an service api will provide jsons. These jsons will hold the layout pattern or design to draw dynamically. 
These layout jsons will coresspond to different templates that we need to show. It can be more than 150 templates.
Please find below a sample template :-

**Template.json**

```
{
"data": {
    "layouts": [
        {
            "layoutId": 0,
            "width": "34%",
            "selectedbackgroundcolor": "#96F2CD",
            "gradient": true,
            "backgroundcolor": "#afeeb9",
            "gradientcolors": [
                "#afeeb9",
                "#f3f6f7"
            ],
            "strokewidth": 1,
            "strokecolor": "#7bad51",
            "children": [
                {
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "backgroundcolor": "#3074c6",
                            "type": "label",
                            "field": "textfield1",
                            "fontsize": 14,
                            "textcolor": "#FFFFFF",
                            "alignment": "right",
                            "width": 242,
                            "singleline": true,
                            "topmargin": 10,
                            "rightmargin": 10,
                            "rightpadding": 10,
                            "bottompadding": 5,
                            "toppadding": 5
                        },
                        {
                            "backgroundcolor": "#3074c6",
                            "type": "label",
                            "text": "textfield: #",
                            "dependonfield": "textfield1",
                            "fontsize": 14,
                            "topmargin": 10,
                            "textcolor": "#FFFFFF",
                            "alignment": "right",
                            "width": 95,
                            "singleline": true,
                            "leftpadding": 10,
                            "bottompadding": 5,
                            "toppadding": 5,
                            "leftmargin": 10
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "type": "label",
                            "field": "FormattedClosedDate",
                            "fontsize": 14,
                            "textcolor": "#000000",
                            "alignment": "right",
                            "width": 90,
                            "topmargin": 5,
                            "singleline": true,
                            "rightmargin": 10
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "label",
                            "text": "Closed On: ",
                            "dependonfield": "FormattedClosedDate",
                            "fontsize": 14,
                            "topmargin": 5,
                            "textcolor": "#000000",
                            "alignment": "right",
                            "width": 100,
                            "singleline": true,
                            "leftmargin": 5,
                            "bold": true
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "type": "label",
                            "field": "Title",
                            "textcolor": "#000000",
                            "alignment": "left",
                            "fontsize": 17,
                            "bold": true,
                            "singleline": true,
                            "topmargin": 10,
                            "leftmargin": 10,
                            "rightmargin": 10
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "type": "label",
                            "field": "Summary",
                            "textcolor": "#7E957B",
                            "alignment": "left",
                            "fontsize": 14,
                            "leftmargin": 10,
                            "bottompadding": 20,
                            "maxline": 2,
                            "rightmargin": 10
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
"rcode": 100,
"msg": "Success"
}
```

I wrote the layout parser for these templates. I choose Listview to dynamically inflate the view that was returned from layout parse. Each listview's row is now holding different layout view or template. 
So I cannot use the view holder pattern to reuse the view's elements. As views are created dynamically so the view id's are created dynamically.

I am showing 15 items in a list at single point of time. I am using this library to load n items form total x items at aingle point in time---https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh.

Now the problems are :-

- Memory leak because we are not using the view holder pattern.
- Context is used to create new views they are coupled from activities
  life cycle.
- Views are not destroyed until activity is not destroyed.

Please provide me with an alternate solution of using other than Listview or modify the current approach.

Comment: View Holder pattern is used to reduce the time required to inflate a list item by reducing the call to findviewbyid which is a expensive operation. It is not used for memory management purposes. ListView generates elements only visible as you scroll more views are generated. So the memory management required is else where. Please post the log cat when the app crashes

Comment: My company policy often forbids me from posting code too.  Best to write a separate (really simple) example demonstrating your problem and post that.  When you post your "distilled" example, make sure you tell people that's what you're doing to prevent the inevitable tide of "Why are you doing that?" questions.

Comment: i will post a sample code on monday.

Comment: I have edited my question fully and made it more understandable

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing for you is be sure to implement [Adapter.getItemViewType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29).  Each layout should have its own type identifier.  Your convertView parameter, if set, will then always have the correct layout already inflated.

Now you can use the holder pattern again, by using a different holder for each layout.

**Edit**: I don't think your situation is well suited to ListView.  ListView is meant for generally large lists of similar content.  Have you considered a vertically oriented LinearLayout within a ScrollView instead?

If your layouts are all different, you have to decide between dynamically generating them in an Adapter (the ListView approach you're already using) which will be slow, or generating them all at once, which *might* take more memory.

As for your specific concerns: 
 * Not using Holder pattern does not introduce a memory leak.  You might be misunderstanding the purpose of Holder pattern.  It's only intended to reduce re-inflation of similar layouts.
 * Even with views created from within an Adapter, they're still created with your activity's context.  They are UI elements, so will always be bound to the Activity lifecycle.

Comment: This solution is when you know beforehand the number of different inflator layouts. In my case they are dynamic and they can be 15 or 150